# Can't Use unlink function with path defined by variable

Tags: php, unlink

I can't read the path by use variable

```
$absPath = realpath('./');
//$absPath = /home/abc/domains/server2.abc.com/public_html/mockup
//$oldPath = /project_image/easy/Desert.jpg
$npath = $absPath."".$oldPath; //$oldPath is get by image element scr="xxx"
```

$npath will return this:

```
/home/abc/domains/server2.abc.com/public_html/mockup/project_image/easy/Desert.jpg
```

When i unlink it

```
unlink($npath);
```

Then php return

```
No such file or directory in /home/../mockup/update_file.php -> point unlink($npath);
```

And i try to Hard Code it

```
$npath = /home/abc/domains/server2.abc.com/public_html/mockup/project_image/easy/Desert.jpg
unlink($npath);
```

Then it will success.

I want to know how to use variable combine a new path to unlink it.

Sorry for my poor English

Comment: you can try to give relative path instead of absoulte path.

Comment: @VikasUmrao still can't unlink it, i tried :(

Comment: is this /mockup/update_file.php suposed to be = to /mockup/project_image/easy/Desert.jpg, minus the file name, because it's not.  You're missing a few folders there namely 'project_image/easy'

Comment: please provide your directory structure...of the folder/file..

Comment: @VikasUmrao
ftp://mockup.server2.abc.com/project_image/TVB8/
here is the FTP i drop file here "ftp://mockup.server2.abc.com/" is the root i save php/html here.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix But when i hard code the path in the variable is work

Comment: Seems like you don't have what you think in that variable when you don't hard code it.., please look at my solution.

Comment: Is Fix, sometime the variable data get from DOM element will have Blank in the string last position. The path will show "/easy/Desert.jpg ", Finally i blind, Thank guy!

Comment: Great to hear! I knew the variable wasn't getting populated correctly. Can you mark my answer as accepted?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you sure your script is producing the exact same path? If you are building the path correctly and unlink is failing, you can try the shell instead. Sometimes this works like with samba mounts and what-not.

```
$absPath = realpath('./');
$npath   = $absPath."".$oldPath;

// Bail if the path doesn't exist
if(!file_exists($npath)) die('Failed to build correct path');

// Try unlink via PHP
if(!unlink($npath) || file_exists($npath)) {

  // PHP couldn't cut it, try unlink via shell
  exec('rm ' . $npath, $output, $return);
  if($return > 0)
    die('Failed to delete file: ' . $npath);
}
```